# Creating a sms reader app to read the incoming messages via text to speech and run in background but it does meet the requirements

Tags: android

```
    **MainActivity.java**


    package com.cetpainfotech.newandroid;

    import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.content.IntentFilter;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.net.Uri;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.provider.ContactsContract;
    import android.provider.ContactsContract.PhoneLookup;
    import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton;
    import android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.ToggleButton;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private final int CHECK_CODE = 0x1;
        private final int LONG_DURATION = 5000;
        private final int SHORT_DURATION = 1200;

        private Speaker speaker;

        private ToggleButton toggle;
        private OnCheckedChangeListener toggleListener;

        private TextView smsText;
        private TextView smsSender;

        private BroadcastReceiver smsReceiver;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            toggle = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.speechToggle);
            smsText = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sms_text);
            smsSender = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sms_sender);

            toggleListener = new OnCheckedChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked) {
                    if(isChecked){
                        speaker.allow(true);
                        speaker.speak(getString(R.string.start_speaking));
                    }else{
                        speaker.speak(getString(R.string.stop_speaking));
                        speaker.allow(false);
                    }
                }
            };
            toggle.setOnCheckedChangeListener(toggleListener);

            checkTTS();
            initializeSMSReceiver();
            registerSMSReceiver();
        }

        private void checkTTS(){
            Intent check = new Intent();
            check.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA);
            startActivityForResult(check, CHECK_CODE);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
            if(requestCode == CHECK_CODE){
                if(resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS){
                    speaker = new Speaker(this);
                }else {
                    Intent install = new Intent();
                    install.setAction(TextToSpeech.Engine.ACTION_INSTALL_TTS_DATA);
                    startActivity(install);
                }
            }
        }

        private void initializeSMSReceiver(){
            smsReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver(){
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

                    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
                    if(bundle!=null){
                        Object[] pdus = (Object[])bundle.get("pdus");
                        for(int i=0;i<pdus.length;i++){
                            byte[] pdu = (byte[])pdus[i];
                            SmsMessage message = SmsMessage.createFromPdu(pdu);
                            String text = message.getDisplayMessageBody();
                            String sender = getContactName(message.getOriginatingAddress());
                            speaker.pause(LONG_DURATION);
                            speaker.speak("You have a new message from" + sender + "!");
                            speaker.pause(SHORT_DURATION);
                            speaker.speak(text);
                            smsSender.setText("Message from " + sender);
                            smsText.setText(text);
                        }
                    }

                }
            };
        }

        private void registerSMSReceiver() {
            IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
            registerReceiver(smsReceiver, intentFilter);
        }

        private String getContactName(String phone){
            Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI, Uri.encode(phone));
            String projection[] = new String[]{ContactsContract.Data.DISPLAY_NAME};
            Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(uri, projection, null, null, null);
            if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
                return cursor.getString(0);
            }else {
                return "unknown number";
            }
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            unregisterReceiver(smsReceiver);
            speaker.destroy();
        }

    }


**Speaker.java** //Helper class
```

This class is used to avoid calling the TTS API directly from the Activity.
This class implements the OnInitListener interface so that it knows when the TTS engine is ready.

package com.cetpainfotech.newandroid;

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.media.AudioManager;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech.OnInitListener;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Speaker implements OnInitListener {

    private TextToSpeech tts;

    private boolean ready = false;

    private boolean allowed = false;

    public Speaker(Context context){
        tts = new TextToSpeech(context, this);
    }

    public boolean isAllowed(){
        return allowed;
    }

    public void allow(boolean allowed){
        this.allowed = allowed;
    }

    @Override
    public void onInit(int status) {
        if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
            // Change this to match your
            // locale
            tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            ready = true;
        }else{
            ready = false;
        }
    }

    public void speak(String text){

        // Speak only if the TTS is ready
        // and the user has allowed speech

        if(ready && allowed) {
            HashMap<String, String> hash = new HashMap<>();
            hash.put(TextToSpeech.Engine.KEY_PARAM_STREAM,
                    String.valueOf(AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION));
            tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, hash);
        }
    }

    public void pause(int duration){
        tts.playSilence(duration, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
    }

    // Free up resources
    public void destroy(){
        tts.shutdown();
    }

}
```